# Google Maps Geocode Results Into An Array

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

I'm trying to output the results of a Google Maps API Geocode query into an array based on a returned qty of results as a console.log (I have added 6 below, but want the qty of console.log to be variable):

```
$(document).ready(function(){

      // Search Submit  
      $("#search").submit(function(event){
            event.preventDefault("", function(){
                  //
                  });

            name = $("#search-name").val();
            console.log("Search term at submit is: "+name);

            // Send to Google Geocoding API

            var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder(); 
            geocoder.geocode({ 
                        address : name
                  }, function(results, status){
                        if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
                              console.log(results[0]);
                              console.log(results[1]);
                              console.log(results[2]);
                              console.log(results[3]);
                              console.log(results[4]);
                              console.log(results[5]);
                        } else {
                              alert("Geocode was not successful for the following reason: " + status);
                        }
                  }
            );
      });
});
```

I've been looking, but I cannot figure out exactly how to go about doing it.

Comment: What's your exact question?

Comment: Hi @MrNeo so at present if I search say Germany, I get 1 return which fills the top console.log.  If I search Main Street, then there are 100's of returns, which I would like to obtain the info in the relevant number of results in additional console logs. So... How do I make the qty of console.logs be variable based on the qty of returned results from the API?

Comment: You mean you want a `variable` which contains `console.log`? like: `variable[1] = console.log(result[1]);`

Comment: Not quite... Are you familiar with the Geocoding return?  The result qty could be 1 location or lots depending on the location sent.  I want to view the results in a console log, no matter how many results are returned.

Comment: You could only use `console.log(results);` and then click on arrow in console to show all result of array

Comment: OK.  Thanks.  I see what you mean :) I'm learning... I'm now going to try & output the info into a html table...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You use a loop:

```
function(results, status ){
  if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
    for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
      console.log(results[i]);
    }
  } else {
    alert("Geocode was not successful for the following reason: " + status);
  }
```